# Masstransit AddMediator() method not exists

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit, mediator

I'm new to use `MassTransit`. to use the mediator.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(options => 
{
    options.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    options.AddMediator(); // this function is not found
    options.AddRequestClient<ISubmitOrder>();
});
```

Which package has the `AddMediator()` extension method?
I'm trying with Masstransit v7.x and cannot find `AddMediator()` method.

Comment: Have you tried [MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection/). [It seems](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5e3b418e26120d21389e122266d3be19178072de/src/Containers/MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration/DependencyInjectionRegistrationExtensions.cs) like it defined in there.

Comment: Yes, I did. and it's not exists

Comment: You should call it on the `ServiceCollection` not on the `options`. So `services.AddMediator();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @Peter Csala,

it's updated now in Masstransit v7.x.

Container configuration has changed, and now uses the `AddMediator` method (instead of `AddMassTransit`. According to. [MassTransit Upgrade](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html)

```
services.AddMediator(options =>
    {
        options.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
        options.AddRequestClient<ISubmitOrder>();
    });
```

Comment: Just for anyone else that comes across this, you'll need to add a reference to MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection as well.